# Activity refresh command from custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, refresh

Environment: Android 2.2+

I have an Activity. The Activity creates a custom listview with its adapter and populates it. When the user clicks on an item (an ImageView thumbnail) in the list, a context menu is shown. The repercussion of selection is that the view of Activity needs to be refreshed.

My question is: How can I send a command from the onClick of the custom adapter to the Activity asking to refresh itself?

**Activity**

```
    ...
    ListView lv;
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvlist);
    lv.setAdapter(null);
    MyCustomAdapter lvAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(...);
    lv.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(myClickListener);
    ...
```

**MyCustomAdapter** (There is a thumbnail ImageView inside each list item called ivLogo)

```
    ...
    ivLogo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Carry out some tasks

            // At this point inform Activity that it needs to refresh
        }
    });
```

It must be noted that I'm not looking for anything in myClickListener. I want a signal from the thumbnail's onClickListener.

I scoured the internet, but could not find anything helpful for this specific case.
Any help/pointers will be much appreciated.

TIA

-sph

Answer (score 0):

> you write his code whenever you need adpater refreshed...its worked

```
lvAdapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your onClick()

```
lvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```